# Azure Compute Vision Service skips a letter

Tags: c#, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am using link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-hand-text to read a hand written image.

**My Issue**

1. Some of the letters it skips reading.
2. Some values in boxes are read as one value\word.

   Is there a way I can address it?
   [image]

*Image above for #1 issue:* The red circled doesn't get read.

*Image above for #2 issue:*  The yellow highlighted is read as one word (like 13.71/89.8/47.5/31.8/7.6|72),

The below image shows the numbers read as one value.
[image]

while the first row is read separately as expected  (i.e 5,1,3.4,129, 72 are read as separate words)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Custom Vision service.  This service allows you to upload and train the model for better accuracy.  Once trained, the service is exposed via an API URL that you can replace in your code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/home

Comment: The image I would be processing will need to identify handwritten data from clients. Can you please give me some pointers on  how to train this kind?

Comment: Sure, we have a tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/getting-started-build-a-classifier

Comment: The tutorial speaks about objects image to be trained. In my case I need to process the image that will have data (numbers with precision and words). I  need to 100% correctly detect  those values with precision. Will this help for my case?

Comment: Statistically, you will never get to 100%, that is why it is called a model.  The best you can get is a model that gets you close enough to 100% to solve your problem.  If you need 100% accuracy, you will most likely need human validation after the model run.

Comment: Its OK on not being always 100%. I'm curios if the Custom Vision Service would support to train\identify the handwritten numbers that would be in the target image. `Note : The expected image will be a snapshot of a application FORM to be filled by the applicants`.

Comment: I don't see why you can't train Custom Vision service with handwritten numbers.  The issue will be accuracy since not all handwriting is legible.  As you can see 3's and 8's are difficult for the vision service to accurately id as will 7's and 1's.

Comment: @jAntoni just give it a try and if the performance is good enough for you, then you can use it.

Comment: @PingJin actually I couldn't get the way how to train the numbers or characters in the image to be processed. With the link mentioned above I couldn't get more further. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like draw a box around the text "7" and label it as a tag "7". Then the trained model can detect positions of "7" in other pics.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code.Need to deliver it asap. THanks in advance.